# exception handling via controller in kohana

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

I am following the tutorial at http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages for **Kohana 3.3**

The following code is at ***classes/http/exception/404.php***

```
 <?php
    class HTTP_Exception_404 extends Kohana_HTTP_Exception_404 {
        public function get_response(){
            $view = View::factory('errors/404');
            $view->message = $this->getMessage();
     
            $response = Response::factory()
                ->status(404)
                ->body($view->render());
     
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

When trying to give an incorrect url like

***localhost/myapp/xyz***

The following error comes up

```
ErrorException [ Parse Error ]:
APPPATH\classes\http\exception\404.php [ 3 ]
1 <?php
2 class HTTP_Exception_404 extends Kohana_HTTP_Exception_404 {
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
{PHP internal call} » Kohana_Core::shutdown_handler()
```

In **bootstrap.php** the code for init is

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/myapp/',
    'errors' => TRUE,
    'index_file' => FALSE,
));
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to check:

- Does the `errors/404` view exist at `APPPATH/views/errors/404.php`?
- Does the class filepath and name use StudlyCaps `APPPATH\Classes\HTTP\Exception\404.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Rename directory with a capital letter
**classes/HTTP/Exception/404.php**